# Sony PRST2 ereader not connecting

Tags: usb, sony

I have old Sony prst2 which I like a lot, since it has loads of dictionaries to use with foreign books and it is still working great by itself. After I moved from Windows 7 to Windows 10 I haven't been able to get the reader to connect to computer. I installed Ubuntu 18.04 dualboot to my laptop (HP Elitebook 820 G3) and thought that linux would not be so picky about usb connections from old devices - but result is the same as with Windows 10: reader does not offer the option to download files nor does it even start to recharge. After the cable has been plugged in for a moment it only states:

> Notice. Not charged.
>   Follow the procedures below to charge:
>   1. Turn on the power of the connecting PC
>   2. Disconnect the USB cable
>   3. Reconnect the USB cable again.
>   See the Users Guide for more details.

Other locations does not show any usb drives and I'm such newbie with Ubuntu that I don't know what else to check nor how to.

Calibre (3.21.0) does not see any ereaders either (on Ubuntu or Windows). With Calibres Connect/Share and Content server I'm able to download the books from the laptop to reader via wifi, but this workaround is somewhat unsatisfactory since I can't use Calibre to manage my ebook library properly. Mostly I just can't believe that even linux can't recognize old usb devices. All I can think is that I would need some really old usb driver and yet I doubt that the problem lays there. Any good ideas for this puzzle?

Comment: Just tried with PRS-T1: it was off, I connected USB, reader loaded (*opening book*), then I activated USB connection (on ebook screen). As the result I got 3 USB-drives (READER, SETTING and MicroSD) in Ubuntu 16.04 LTS, Calbre sees it. You can try to check settings on the reader.

Comment: Thanks, but this does not work on prst2 and Ubuntu 18.04, prst2 does not offer anymore the usb connection choice (or any other) as it normally has done when connected. Can't find anything concerning usb from the settings either.

Comment: I have just tried the same PRS-T1 with Calibre on Ubuntu 18.04 LTS - it works normally (in aforementioned manner). So really consider to check settings of the reader. Or backup its books and reset to factory defaults. Other possible problem is USB connection - try to clean USB socket on the reader and/or change USB cable between reader and computer.

Comment: Since then has both Ubuntu and Windows 10 updated and probably because this Calibre now sees my Sony prst2 on both platforms, eg. didn't need to do anything to fix this. Strange world.